# whick one is better fkeditor or ckeditor?

Tags: ckeditor, fckeditor

i am running through a problem to choose either fkeditor or ckeditor which one is better than the other in my project. and how can i get the tutorial regarding customization of any one of these editor in php.
Can you name some websites where i could get the help thanks.

Comment: I alredy used [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) in some projects and it is very good because is easy to install and have good docs in its site. If you want to upload photos and files you can do the integration with [CKFinder](http://ckfinder.com/) which is very good too.

Answer (score 6):

CKEditor is formerly known as FCKEditor (the creator was unaware that FCKEditor didn't sound very... professional) - so you'll want CKEditor.

The [CKEditor website](http://docs.cksource.com/) has a wealth of information - check out the [User Guide](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Users_Guide), [Tutorials](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Tutorials) and [How Tos](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Howto). Also, when you have downloaded the CKEditor file, you'll find some example code in ckeditor/_samples/php which should help.

Comment: `CKEditor` was formerly named `FCKEditor`.

Comment: That is pretty much what I said in the first six words isn't it?

Comment: You missed `C` in that name. You missed it twice so I thought it's not a simple typo.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that you're John `C`. :)

Comment: @rasheed if you are happy [marking the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) as correct is the best thanks :-)